# How to add a reaction to a message using the message ID

Tags: python, discord, message, discord.py

I want to make a Bot command, that adds a reaction to a message when given emoji and ID of the message.

It seems like I need to turn the string I get from the original message into the `discord.Message` class for the code to work, but I don't find any way of doing that.

I've already read through the documentation and it just says 
"There should be no need to create one of these manually."

```py
import discord
token = "Token Here"
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("e react"):
        msg_id = message.content[8:26] #This filters out the ID
        emoji = message.content[27:] #This filters out the Emoji
        await msg_id.add_reaction(emoji)

client.run(token)
```

I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'`

Answer (score 0):

This is made much easier by using [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters).  Specifically, we can use [`MessageConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MessageConverter) to get the target `Message` object and [`PartialEmojiConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.PartialEmojiConverter) to get the emoji we want to react with:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Message, PartialEmoji

bot = Bot("e ")

@bot.command()
async def react(ctx, message: Message, emoji: PartialEmoji):
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```